# NaN values in dataframe of dtype int is not getting filled

Tags: pandas

I read data as `pd.read_csv()` now i want to fill all the NaN values. So for that i

```
all_data.isna().sum()
```

then o/p

```
id             0
bin_0      29795
```

And

```
all_data['bin_0'].value_counts()
```

O/p is

```
0.0    880154
1.0     90051
Name: bin_0, dtype: int64
```

And converting using

```
all_data['bin_0'] = all_data['bin_0'].fillna(all_data['bin_0'].mode()[0])
all_data['bin_0'].value_counts()
```

Then output is

```
0.0    880154
1.0     90051
nan     29795
Name: bin_0, dtype: int64
```

It does not filll nan value

Comment: is `nan` the `np.nan` values or the string `'nan'`?

Comment: @QuangHoang Updated the question. Please have a look